# SQLCODE Error -122

Tags: sql, group-by

I'm not used to SQL a lot, so maybe my question is so dumb, don't be hard with me guys ;)

So, this is my table PEOPLE, and what i want is with a query is find the people that are not in an expecific age, but im getting an error.

```
    PEOPLE
+-------+------+---------+
| NUMPOL|  MCT |  PRODNUM|
+-------+------+---------+
| 98552 | 1054 |   9704  | 
+-------+------+---------+
| 89854 | 0985 |   5014  | 
+-------+------+---------+
| 78542 | 1054 |   9704  | 
+-------+------+---------+
| 98552 | 0965 |   9704  | 
+-------+------+---------+
| 98552 | 4222 |   9704  | 
+-------+------+---------+
```

I'm trying to run this query

```
SELECT NUMPOL, MCT, PRODCO
FROM  PEOPLE                         
WHERE MCT NOT IN (1054,0965) AND PRODNUM='9704'
GROUP BY NUMPOL
```

And this is the error that I'm getting, I tried to solve it googling but never could find an answer because I can't find why it told me that the select list is not valid:

```
SQLCODE = -122, ERROR:  COLUMN OR EXPRESSION IN THE SELECT LIST IS
NOT VALID
```

Comment: Why are you using `group by`  if you are not aggregating? What exactly are you trying to achieve with that? It seems the `group by` is not needed at all. Please [edit] your question and add the expected output based on your sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY :

```
SELECT TEAM, [NAME], AGE
FROM  PEOPLE                         
WHERE AGE NOT IN (20,21,22,23) AND GEND='F'
GROUP BY TEAM
```

`NAME` is an SQL keyword.

Comment: I changed the column names for the example, the problem isnt the keywords guys ://, In my real database the names of the columns are more complex but is the same thing

Comment: You have changed the name so that it may cause a mistake, not our fault that we have paid attention to it @GONZALOPANIAGUA

Comment: You want to group by `TEAM`, let's say `TEAM =' A '` what should be in the column`NAME`? John, Juls, Luxu? Your query is wrong because when you group after the `TEAM` column, sql does not know what to display in the other columns in your SELECT list. @GONZALOPANIAGUA

Comment: I edited the question, can you find the mistake now? Thanks btw for allt he help @KillerQueen

Comment: Sure, do you understand my earlier comment? @GONZALOPANIAGUA

Comment: The problem is I dont want to group by an exactly NUMPOL, I mean: I want to find the NUMPOLs that dont have the MCT, but if the NUMPOL 98552 alrady have a row with that MCT i dont want it to get displayed, but it will be displayed because there's a row with the MCT '0965' @KillerQueen

Comment: something like that : `SELECT NUMPOL
FROM  PEOPLE                         
WHERE MCT IS NULL AND NUMPOL NOT IN (SELECT NUMPOL FROM PEOPLE WHERE MCT IS NOT NULL )` ? @GONZALOPANIAGUA

Comment: The double select could work, Thanks :) @Killer Queen

Comment: I m glad that i could help, have nice day :) @GONZALOPANIAGUA

Comment: `NAME` is *not* a SQL reserved word.

Answer (score 2):

Read the error message :

COLUMN OR EXPRESSION IN THE SELECT LIST IS NOT VALID

Since it mentions the "SELECT LIST", inspect the SELECT LIST :

NUMPOL, MCT, PRODCO

Look for where there's a column named "PRODCO" in your table.

Answer (score 1):

Group by has some [rules](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=664143&seqNum=6)

```
SELECT NUMPOL, MCT, PRODCO
FROM  PEOPLE                         
WHERE MCT NOT IN (1054,0965) AND PRODNUM='9704'
GROUP BY NUMPOL,MCT, PRODCO
```

Comment: does it help @GONZALO